# what is the criteria for displaying invalid data in a list?

Tags: lists, validation, sorting

I have an App that is holding a list of gas stations and those can be sorted by Price so the user can see first the ones with cheaper prices...

now, the requirement is that if the price I get from web-server is older than 2 days it must be somehow displayed in another way...

I was thinking:

1. changing the color of the price (they said is not valid since the text color must be the same always)
2. adding an info mark like 1.33$ * (they said is not valid since i need to add a new line at the end explaining what that means)
3. moving those prices to the bottom of the list and somehow strike them like  <strike>1,35 $</strike>

[image]

but am not sure which of those options is the best one for the UX-UI...

thanks

Comment: post a mockup of the work you've done so far, and the community can help give you a more informed answer...

Comment: When you say "they said is not valid" who are you talking about and in what way were the options not valid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about displaying it the UX.SE way?

---

[image]

---

## Update

[image]

Comment: that looks very good, but my view-layout if defined and can not be modified... it must looks more or less like: https://lh5.ggpht.com/XRXycamUzxhR8L7gvUNDvJe70AmGOOyIEXsemW9zubch7UlUOwuR0qUDgA-wnOouVB8=h900

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ Check the update

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ for future reference, please post an image in your question. It makes it clearer for everyone what you're asking.